# how to remove undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

When I am adding a new rule in table, it is displaying "undefined". But in controller to jsp it is returning the correct value. If I print the value in alert it is printing the exact value. But only problem its displaying "undefined". After refreshing the page, it is showing the correct value.

I have given table refresh also. But I dont know why it is displaying undefined. Please help me how can I resolve this?

```js
var ajaxObj = {
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) { 
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><font size="2" >Please wait...</font></h1>'  });
    jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').trigger('click');
  }
   }; 
         
    $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxObj, {
    url: "draftPoolRulesAdd", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function () {
                
    $( "#poolrules_tab_main" ).pqGrid( "addRow", { rowData: {"poolRuleId":ruleId,"poolruleSeq":1,"poolRuleName":ruleName,"poolRuleComment":comments,"poolruleCondition":a.toString(),
 "poolruleValue":b.toString(),"poolruleDataType":'Y',"poolruleAddPoints":c.toString()} } );
      
    alert("pool rule name" + ruleName);  
      
    if(AdditionalPoolPoints ()){
    $.unblockUI();
              
    $('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').parent().remove(); 
   $.jGrowl("Rule was successfully Added", {  life:1500 });
    $.jGrowl.defaults.pool = 1;
    $("#poolrules_tab_main").pqGrid("refreshDataAndView");
   }
     }
   }));
```

In success function I am printing one alert. Here it is printing the exact pool rule name. But in screen only it is displaying "undefined". Please help me for this.

Comment: Where are `ruleId`, `ruleName` and `comments` defined? And, if you could put the alert before adding the row, and see what value of `ruleName` it is showing.

Comment: If I put ruleName, before adding row also its displying exact value. ruleId,ruleName and comments everything has displying in console. But in frontend only it is displying "undefined". After refreshing the page it is showing the correct value.

Comment: What happens if you hardcode somevalue in place of `ruleName` while adding the row, does it still display undefined?

Comment: yes if I hardcode a value also its displaying "undefined" only.

Comment: As per the documentation [here](http://paramquery.com/pro/api#method-addRow), row names are not inside quotes, you can try that and make sure that row names are correct.

Comment: I have given every row name has correct only. The value also printed in console. In screen only its showing "undefined".